# How to count 3 different vowels

Tags: javascript

I want to check if my string has 3 *different* vowels. Mine code below counts every vowel regardless if they are the same.

```js
function hasThreeVowels(str) {
    let vowelCount = 0;
    let vowels = "aeiou"
    
    for (let char of str) {
        if(vowels.includes(char)) {
            vowelCount++
        }
    }
    return vowelCount >= 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep track of the vowels you used and only increase the `vowelCount` if the vowel is not used yet.

```js
function hasThreeDifferentVowels(str) {
  let vowelCount = 0;
  let vowels = 'aeiou';
  let usedVowels = { a: false, e: false, i: false, o: false, u: false };

  for (let char of str) {
    if (vowels.includes(char) && !usedVowels[char]) {
      vowelCount++;
      usedVowels[char] = true;
    }
  }
  return vowelCount >= 3;
}

console.log(hasThreeDifferentVowels('abaacaaeevaa'));
console.log(hasThreeDifferentVowels('abaacaaeevai'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code below:

```
function hasThreeVowels(str) {
  let vowelCount = 0;
  let vowels = 'aeiou';
  let vowelsObj = {
    a: 0,
    e: 0,
    i: 0,
    o: 0,
    u: 0,
  };

  for (let char of str) {
    if (vowels.includes(char)) {
      if (vowelsObj[char] === 0) {
        vowelsObj[char] = 1;
        vowelCount++;
      }
    }
  }

  return vowelCount >= 3;
}
```

To check if a given string to the `hasThreeVowels()` has three distinct vowels in it, I would create a `vowelsObject` with keys being each vowel and values 0. Then after looping through each character of the given string, I will check:
1- If the character is vowel or not
2- If yes, I will check if the value of that vowel in the `vowelsObject` is 0
3- If yes, I will set the value to be one and increase the counter.

Comment: Why would you use two loops here? Ah, okay, you've already edited it :)

Comment: I removed the second loop in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the vowels as a Set (of 5). Then subtract each character from that set and if the set's size reduces to just 2, then you know there have been 3 distinct vowels:

```js
function hasThreeVowels(str) {
    const vowels = new Set("aeiou");
    return [...str].some(ch => vowels.delete(ch) && vowels.size < 3);
}

console.log(hasThreeVowels('fantastic')); // false
console.log(hasThreeVowels('amazing')); // false
console.log(hasThreeVowels('fabulous')); // true
console.log(hasThreeVowels('awesome')); // true
```

I find the use of `some` elegant, but it will run somewhat faster with a `for` loop.